# SqlConnection.Close() does not seem to really close the MS SQL connection

Tags: .net, sqlconnection

this relates both to .Net development and MS SQL database management. Having developer roots myself, I am posting it here.

We are currently analyzing some issues on one of our MS SQL servers. I noticed that even after the Close() method call of an System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection instance in the application, the connection on the MS SQL server stays there. It has the status "sleeping" and cmd "awaiting command" (I use the sp_who on the MS SQL server to check the existing connections). It finally disappears when the application itself closes. In some cases there are several hundreds such connections on the server. I can observe this behavior on MS SQL servers 2008 to 2014.

Questions:

Is it "normal"? If yes, how many such connections can be considered ok(ayish) on an MS SQL 2008 with 4 cores and 32 GB RAM?
Is it "bad" for the MS SQL server - do these sleeping connections consume or block resources?

Thanks in advance

Best regards,

Erich

Comment: Application keeps a pool of connections and when you do `.Open()` it looks for a first free connection from a pool. Max pool size is 100, but each conneciton string has its own pool. I don't think these connections take much resources, but they take some time to create. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the link, it helped.